# error 1282 opengl es 2.0 uploading active texture to sampler

Tags: android, graphics, 3d, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I´m developing my own game engine, and I´m finding some weird behaviour.
Uploading an active uniform to a sampler works perfect in Genymotion (emulating an nexus 6 platform) but fails in my real moto g (2014 generation).

This is a screen capture of the Genymotion:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bmPv.jpg

and this is the caputure of my moto g device:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWxO6.png

If you get near enought to some objects you can see the right color (in the table, in the stool or the telescope) in some small parts of the figure.

Also while uploading the current active texture to the sampler in fragment shader in getting these errors:

```
03-18 18:07:46.882  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero V/GLSurfaceView﹕ glGetString(7937) returns Adreno (TM) 305;
03-18 18:07:47.059  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:319>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-18 18:07:50.166  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ - error uploading uniform -Material.diffuseTexture: glError 1282
03-18 18:07:50.167  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:319>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-18 18:07:50.375  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ - error uploading uniform -Material.specularTexture: glError 1282
03-18 18:07:50.375  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:319>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-18 18:07:50.527  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ - error uploading uniform -Material.emissionTexture: glError 1282
03-18 18:07:50.527  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:319>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-18 18:07:50.676  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ - error uploading uniform -Material.ambientTexture: glError 1282
03-18 18:07:56.106  12470-12486/com.manu.juegos.half_hero I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 46970(1992KB) AllocSpace objects, 28(5MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.082ms total 172.565ms
03-18 18:08:09.332  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:340>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-18 18:08:10.326  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ - error uploading uniform -Material.diffuseTexture: glError 1282
03-18 18:08:10.334  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:340>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-18 18:08:11.247  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ - error uploading uniform -Material.specularTexture: glError 1282
03-18 18:08:11.247  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <__load_uniform_int:340>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-18 18:08:12.086  12470-13180/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ - error uploading uniform -Material.emissionTexture: glError 1282
```

I'm not getting all these errors in Genymotion emulator.

This is the code I use for upload the active uniform for each texture to the sampler:

```
public void uploadTextureUnits_to_samplers(){
    for (Texture.TextureType type : Texture.TextureType.values()) {
        this.uploadUniformData(type.getSamplerString(), type.getTextureUnit());
    }
}

public void uploadUniformData(String uniformName, Object value){
    // triplet: locator, dataType, dataValue
    Map<String, Triplet<Integer, Integer, Object>> mapa_programa = GlProgram.m_Uniform_Cache_Store.get(m_GL_Program_ID);
    if (mapa_programa == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("GlProgram.uploadUniformData: mapa de programa no inicializado");
    }
    Triplet<Integer, Integer, Object> uniform_data = mapa_programa.get(uniformName);

    if (uniform_data == null){
        return; // por ejemplo normal texture no está implementado y no estará declarado en el shader
    }

    uniform_data.m_Z = value;
    Integer dataType = uniform_data.m_Y;
    Integer location = uniform_data.m_X;

    int[] intValArr = null;
    float[] floatValArr = null;
    int matrixCounterToUpload = 1;
    Integer intVal = null;

    switch (dataType) { // tipo de dato del uniform
        case GLES20.GL_INT:
            intVal = (Integer) value;
            GLES20.glUniform1i(location, intVal);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_INT_VEC2:
            intValArr = (int[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform2i(location, intValArr[0], intValArr[1]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_INT_VEC3:
            intValArr = (int[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform3i(location, intValArr[0], intValArr[1], intValArr[2]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_INT_VEC4:
            intValArr = (int[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform4i(location, intValArr[0], intValArr[1], intValArr[2], intValArr[3]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FLOAT:
            Float floatVal = (Float) value;
            GLES20.glUniform1f(location, floatVal);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FLOAT_VEC2:
            floatValArr = (float[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform2f(location, floatValArr[0], floatValArr[1]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FLOAT_VEC3:
            floatValArr = (float[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform3f(location, floatValArr[0], floatValArr[1], floatValArr[2]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FLOAT_VEC4:
            floatValArr = (float[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform4f(location, floatValArr[0], floatValArr[1], floatValArr[2], floatValArr[3]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FLOAT_MAT2:
            floatValArr = (float[]) value;
            matrixCounterToUpload = 1; // no subimos array de matrices sino solo una matriz, al menos aquí
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix2fv(location, matrixCounterToUpload, false, floatValArr, 0);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FLOAT_MAT3:
            floatValArr = (float[]) value;
            matrixCounterToUpload = 1; // no subimos array de matrices sino solo una matriz, al menos aquí
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix3fv(location, matrixCounterToUpload, false, floatValArr, 0);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FLOAT_MAT4:
            floatValArr = (float[]) value;
            matrixCounterToUpload = 1; // no subimos array de matrices sino solo una matriz, al menos aquí
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(location, matrixCounterToUpload, false, floatValArr, 0);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_BOOL:
            intVal = (Integer) value;
            GLES20.glUniform1i(location, intVal);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_BOOL_VEC2:
            intValArr = (int[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform2i(location, intValArr[0], intValArr[1]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_BOOL_VEC3:
            intValArr = (int[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform3i(location, intValArr[0], intValArr[1], intValArr[2]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_BOOL_VEC4:
            intValArr = (int[]) value;
            GLES20.glUniform4i(location, intValArr[0], intValArr[1], intValArr[2], intValArr[3]);
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_SAMPLER_2D:
            intVal = (Integer) value;
            GLES20.glUniform1i(location, intVal);
            break;
    }
    this.checkGLError("- error uploading uniform -" + uniformName);
}
```

And this is the definition of TextureType, used to upload the active uniform to the sampler in shader:

```
public static enum TextureType {
    DIFFUSE_MAP(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0, Material.GLSL_MATERIAL_DIFFUSE_TEXTURE),
    NORMAL_MAP(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0+1, Material.GLSL_MATERIAL_NORMAL_TEXTURE),
    SPECULAR_MAP(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0+2, Material.GLSL_MATERIAL_SPECULAR_TEXTURE),
    EMISSION_MAP(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0+3, Material.GLSL_MATERIAL_EMISSION_TEXTURE),
    AMBIENT_MAP(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0+4, Material.GLSL_MATERIAL_AMBIENT_TEXTURE);

    int m_Texture_Unit = -1;
    String m_Sampler_String = null;

    TextureType(int GL_TEXTURE_UNIT, String samplerString){ // (texture unit, glsl sampler uniform string)
        m_Texture_Unit = GL_TEXTURE_UNIT;
        m_Sampler_String = samplerString;
    }

    public int getTextureUnit(){
        return this.m_Texture_Unit;
    }

    public String getSamplerString(){
        return this.m_Sampler_String;
    }
}

;
```

I am not able to find what's going on. Can anyone see what's wrong ?

EDIT:

As @RetoKoradi sugested, I was not calling glUseProgram. However now i´m getting differents errors depending on the machine I'm executing the code. In genymotion (emulation a nexus 6 machine) I get the next one:

```
- error uploading uniform -Material.diffuseTexture: glError 1281
```

However the scene is rendered well (although not all, some assets are not being drawn)

In the Moto G I have the next error:

```
03-19 19:45:27.453    4954-5112/com.manu.juegos.half_hero W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <validate_samplers:252>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
03-19 19:45:27.453    4954-5112/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/framework.GLProg error:﹕ post Vertices3D.draw(): glError 1282
```

Comment: Are you calling `glUseProgram()` before making the `glUniform*()` calls?

Comment: Thanks @RetoKoradi . This was the problem. However now I have a new (I think related) problem. In the moment of drawing I get the next message: <validate_samplers:252>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION. What do you think could be happening ?

Comment: At this point I can add that Genymotion throws another different error: - error uploading uniform -Material.diffuseTexture: glError 1281

Comment: Do I need to bind some texture with glBindTexture or activate some texture unit with glActiveTexture before uploading the texture units to the sampler ?